# How to split a string with <br> in Ruby

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I am using Nokogiri to search for some information on a webpage. After I find it I get the following string:

```
<p></p>
<p>Spiegel Institut Communication GmbH &amp; Co. KG i. G.<br>Eastsite 
VI<br>Hermsheimer Straße 5<br>D-68163 Mannheim<br>Telefon: +49 621-728 44-
444<br>Telefax: +49 621-728 44-445<br>E-Mail: b.weber@spiegel-
institut.de<br>Geschäftsführer:<br>Dipl.-Kfm. Götz Spiegel<br>Amtsgericht 
Mannheim<br>Inhaltlich Verantwortlicher gemäß § 10 Absatz 3 MDStV: Götz 
Spiegel (Anschrift wie oben)</p>
```

It is all a single line. I would like to separate the String on the 
 into a new line so I can get the single details from it. How do I go about it? I am new to Ruby and I have tried but somehow I cannot get the results I want.

Thank you very much

Comment: html_safe method  can help you out to use context as html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's relatively simple, using the [split](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-split) method on the string. For example:

```
 'this<br>that<br> the other'.split("<br>")
```

Will result in

```
 ["this", "that", " the other"]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just use the split method:

```
string.split('<br>')
```